# Libraries for Object Oriented on C Language

Tags: c, linux, oop

this is a simple question that have around my head for some time, im really not need it now, but, can i use the kernel source code elements like kobject as alternative to GObject for OO on C, or is it exclusive for kernel level? i mean, can i use it on application dev as OO C library?

Comment: It is exclusive to the kernel. You can always pull from the kernel source, but it is a mix of macros and code that may be a bit hard to follow. You may benefit from [Object Oriented Programming in ANSI C](https://book.huihoo.com/pdf/object-oriented-programming-with-ansi-c/ooc.pdf) (especially chapters 2-3) which covers an approach and introduces data hiding/encapsulation. It will be a challenge for someone not completely familiar with the language, but it is reasonably well written. That said, this question is Off-Topic on this site.

Comment: Thats what iam thinking, thanks, ill check that document, or i can use GObject,  after all its not a bad option, what you think?

Comment: `GOject` is fine -- I use it with Gtk+2 (or if I have to Gtk+3). You are much better off using a tested method rather than writing your own (there is nothing wrong with writing your own, but using a method that had literally thousands and thousands of programmer using it ensures is has been vigorously tested -- verses what you come up with overnight `:)` It depends on what you need. I regularly write my own lists, stacks, queues, trees, etc... if what I needs isn't provided, but I'm not against using what a library provides, e.g. [gtkwrite](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite) uses both.

Comment: Yes, as i say in my ask, im not really needed now, but is good to keep in mind, i think GObject or another OO help in C can be very useful and accelerate dev process on medium/large project that need to be develop on C, thanks again, thats leave me much more clear.